# modular exponentation for RSA, why is 2^16 + 1 commonly chosen?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography

I know that the number 2<sup>16</sup> + 1 is commonly used for RSA, since 0b 1 0000 0000 0000 0001 only contains two 1 bits. Many sites explain that this makes modular exponentiation faster, but I haven't come across an explanation of why it is faster.

Why is it more efficient to use a number with a lot of zeros for modular exponentiation?

Comment: I don't think this is exactly a theoretical question, but I wouldn't mind seeing the answer myself!

Comment: I don't think "theoretical" per se is a requirement here.

Comment: i think this is a fine question, but i do wish that more questions would use correct capitalization.  i find it hard to read uncapitalized posts, and it comes across as unprofessional.

Comment: @Theo, I would encourage you to start downvoting with this as a reason. I'll try to as well! "-1, inability to use <shift> key."

Comment: @Theo, Scott: why not just edit the post? It's not worth editing for tiny grammatical things, but if it's enough for you to leave a comment or a downvote, I think it's better to just edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a two minor advantages to choosing the exponent 2<sup>16</sup>+1.

The first advantage, as Johannes observed, is that for fixed size exponent, exponentiation to power e using the [basic repeated squaring method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) is moderately faster when e has lots of zero bits. It is not true that exponents with more one bits are necessarily slower since there are plenty of such numbers with very short [addition chains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation) (though finding such short addition chains is an NP complete problem in general). In any case, e = 3 would be a much better choice than e = 2<sup>16</sup>+1 for the sole purpose of exponentiation.

The second advantage is that 2<sup>16</sup>+1 is a prime number and it is not too small. A requirement of the RSA algorithm is that the exponent e must be relatively prime with φ(pq) = (p-1)(q-1). Since the large primes p and q are chosen randomly, there is always a chance that (p-1)(q-1) is not relatively prime with the (previously chosen) exponent e and the primes p,q must therefore be discarded. So small exponents e are poor choices since about every (e-1)<sup>th</sup> choice of p and q is a bad one, thus shrinking the overall key space. Choosing e to be a large prime would be best, but too large an e would make exponentiation slow. In the end, e = 2<sup>16</sup>+1 is a nice compromise value.

Comment: I guess a third advantage of 65537 is that it is the smallest exponent allowed by NIST, though they don't give a specific reason for that choice. (Probably to avoid small exponent attacks, which are possible when proper padding is not used.)

Comment: @François G. Dorais: If e=3, couldn't you just avoid generating primes that are 1 mod 3?  I assume 0 mod 2 and 3 are being avoided already to save some time.  It's not hard to take a random number k and consider 6k+5 as a potential prime.

Comment: Yes, that is fine for e=3. It is already difficult for e=5 without further decreasing the key space and/or increasing the key-generation cost. (Note that the real issue with e=3 is the risk of small exponent attacks.)

Comment: Also, e=3 has the disadvantage that it might be vulnerable to the broadcast attack. If you send a message x using e=3 to 3 different users (with different n_1,n_2,n_3, WLOG, mutually relatively prime (or we'd have a factorisation of 2 of them..) then we could solve x^3 mod n_i (i=1,2,3) using the CRT for x. 
This is a problem if e=3 were a common exponent. Hence the choice for a relatively large e (also prime and few bits set).

Comment: For why security authorities recommend $e=2^{16}+1$ rather than $e=3$, see [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/18315/555).

Answer (score 8):

The usually used fast exponentiation algorithm is the so called square-and-multiply-algorithm. It needs exactly n+m multiplications, where n is the total length of the binary written exponent and m is the number of 1-bits in the exponent. Therefore exponentation with 2^16+1 is almost twice as fast as exponentiation with say 2^17-1.

Comment: hi
thank you for your answer!
can I ask, though, why does it need m+n operations?  where is that coming from?
thanks again!

Comment: Consider how you might compute something like $5^9$ rapidly.  First, compute the numbers $p_0 = 5^{2^0}$, $p_1 = 5^{2^1}$, $p_2 = 5^{2^2}$, and $p_3 = 5^{2^3}$.  Each of these is computed from the previous one by squaring, so you have $n-1$ multiplications in total (or $n$ if you start by multiplying 1 by 5 to get $5^{2^0}$).  Since 9 is 1001 in binary, you get $5^9$ by multiplying $p_0$ by $p_3$, for $m - 1$ more multiplications (again, $m$ if you start by multiplying 1).  In total, we used four multiplications, where you might naively have used nine.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it more efficient to use a number with a lot of zeros for modular exponentiation?

This didn't seem to be answered directly. Optimal addition chain lengths and construction (for say integer $n$) are known when $v(n)$ is small. $v(n)$ is the Hamming weight (number of 1 bits in the binary representation).
The length of the smallest addition chain for $n$ is denoted $l(n)$. Simple bounds prove the following addition chain to be optimal:
$1,2,4,...,2^{16},2^{16}+1$.
If $l(n)=d$ then $n \leq 2^d$ since you can at most double for each step. So $l(2^{16}+1) \geq 17$. The construction of the chain above completes the proof that $l(2^{16}+1)=17$.
Now in general the larger $v(n)$ the more non-doubling steps you need in a chain. Doubling does not increase the number of 1's in a number but general multiplies do. Non-doubling steps can at most double the number of ones.
We expect that $l(n) \geq \lfloor log_2(n) \rfloor+log_2(v(n))$ but it remains unproven except for small $v(n)$ values and computer searches for $n \leq 2^{64}$ We spit chain steps into two types. With a chain of $1=a_0,a_1,...,a_d=n$ if $\lfloor log_2(a_i) \rfloor= \lfloor log_2(a_{i+1}) \rfloor$ we say step $i$ is a small step. Otherwise it's a large or big step.
Calculating optimal addition chains is all about reducing the small steps. We feel that the small step count ($s(n)=l(n)-\lfloor log_2(n) \rfloor$) is a measure of the complexity of $n$. Non-doubling steps eventually add to the small step count since $s(n) \geq f/3.271$ (see Knuth vol 2 4.6.3 Theorem A) with $f$ as the number of non-doubling steps.